# Can't seem to change the name of a region from GADM shapefile in R shiny leaflet

Tags: r, shiny, polygon

I want to be able to produce a shiny leaflet output with regions, taken from gadm shapefiles, coloured as I see fit.

The trouble, is that there are funny place names in Scotland where I am trying to print these.

[image: See R output of funny spelling]

I have tried going in a changing the name in the code:

[image: See code I tried]

And that does look to be working when I run it in the console. But when I run it as a shiny file, it breaks and seems to be ignoring that code.

[image: See where I put the data into the server]

Is there a way to fix this? Do I need to save new shapefiles with names that are from the regular alphabet?

Answer (score 1):

Seems an encoding problem to me. Try to set it to UTF8.

`Encoding(Scot4@data$NAME_4) <- "UTF-8"`

Comment: Solid idea. I will give that a go.